# xcopy batch for Ark save files

Tags: batch-file, save, xcopy

I'm trying to create a batch file that will copy my original save file and rename it with the date and time into the new destination as soon as its modified by the game (Ark: Survival Evolved). Unfortunately no new files are being created in the destination folder.

After hours of screwing around and browsing forums I thought I better bring it to the experts! I'm not sure if I'd have to add more code so its runs indefinitely? And also how would I stop the batch file say when I'm closing down the server?

```
xcopy "C:\arkserver\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArks\TheCenter.ark" "C:\arkserver\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArks\130MinuteBackupSections\TheCenter - %date:/=-% %time::=-%.ark" /d
```

I know this is a loaded question and I hope I've given enough/not to much information so thank you for your time!

> For those wondering or looking for a solution to this problem of Ark save
>   files every 2 hours: This script is intended to backup your YourMap.ark
>   new save file before it is overwritten at each save interval (default
>   15mins) instead of the game server backing up the game every 2hr 10min

Comment: Can we first check the content of those two system variables, type `ECHO [%DATE%] [%TIME%]` into a command prompt window and let us know the output.

Comment: Why not run the batch file as a scheduled task?

Comment: [Fri 09/16/2016] [ 2:31:53.36]

Comment: @Squashman I have never used task scheduler but does it allow me to set a trigger as a file modification?

Comment: And you're happy with this as a name, "TheCenter - Fri 09-16-2016 2-31-53.36.ark"?

Comment: @Trr1ppy, not understanding your question.

Comment: @Compo perfectly happy with the name

Comment: @Squashman I'm just wondering how I could use task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, while not elegant gets the job done.

```
:ArkSave
copy "C:\arkserver\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArks\TheCenter.ark" "C:\arkserver\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArks\130MinuteBackupSections\TheCenter - %time::=-%.ark"
forfiles -p "C:\arkserver\ShooterGame\Saved\SavedArks\130MinuteBackupSections" -s -m *.* /D -1 /c "cmd /c del @path"
timeout 900
GOTO ArkSave
```

- `Timeout 900` = 900 seconds = 15 minutes

Set this to your save interval; Take care that the time interval is not set below 60 as this could flood your machine with redundant saves.

- `/D -1` = 1 day

Set this to how many days (positive integer) you want the backup files to be kept for or remove forfiles line to keep them indefinitely.

Some limitations of code is that the file might copy midway through being saved resulting in a corrupt file: Solution is to run the save file midway through your save interval.

The purpose of renaming with the time is to stop file name clashes.

Hope this can help anyone else in the same situation

Edit: Ditched xcopy as I don't need the functionality